# In order to avoid spam, can't we add reCaptcha?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, captcha

This is a good resource site wherein users,professors,etc interact
   with each other and help others thereby improving their own
   knowledge.Such a resource pool would be efficient only if we can have
   0 spams in the pool.

Although one point agreed is its difficult to avoid spams but can't
   we reduce it.My suggestion to it would be providing reCaptcha in
   asking questions as well as answering them.

Doing so we can definitely reduce a lot of spams in the future and
   provide a cleaner platform where there is no unnecessary Q&A for
   spams

Comment: We already have anti-spam measures in place. Where exactly do you suggest we add a captcha? How much spam do you actually see on the sites, that makes you feel spam is a problem we have here?

Comment: Oh, and having a captcha doesn't not mean 0 spam. Not even close.

Comment: well i agree but it's just for the asking a question at the last where you click on submit or when u submit an answer

Comment: that's what i agreed to in my question just way to reduce it no more or no less

Comment: Reduce it from what? Do you see any spam around?

Comment: okay not reduce but avoid.Right now no spams have been sighted but some answers are like completely irrelevant to the question asked.These would be voted down or simply sent to the moderator to review

Comment: I did not see much spam, but lots low quality question. but captcha can't stop people post low quality question

Comment: How would adding a captcha stop people from posting bad/irrelevant answers?

Comment: for irrelevant answers if only registered members with a specified rank answer then mostly irrelevant answers stop

Comment: Um, Stack Exchange already uses Captchas, and has for some time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve . The spammers we get clearly appear to be humans working around all anti-spam measures we put into place (thus the use of bit.ly links to avoid blacklists, the continuously shifting IP addresses once one is blocked, the careful wording of spam to make it look like a legitimate answer, etc.).

Comment: This is a legitimate feature request (even if I don't agree with it).  Please stop using the close button because of disagreement, that is what voting is for.

Comment: @BradLarson Could you please check.Not all sites of Stack exchange use Captcha. Sites like Android Enthusiasts only use Captcha

Comment: Any captcha that is worthwhile implementing is a pain for normal users. To stop spam, they have to be so warped that reading them is hard, and so becomes annoying to use. This would most certainly deter answers. So then your attempt to improve quality by reducing spam, also reduces site quality by losing many answers. Besides, you still haven't answered Oded - what spam? I see spam, but I also see it blitzed and nuked in seconds by community voting and flagging.

Answer (score 9):

StackExchange sites already have [community moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), a ranked [privilege system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), and some anti-flooding measures, which have proven effective in preventing / dealing with spam.

Moderators can also [protect popular questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), which are specifically targeted by spammers because of their popularity.

These systems make it very difficult for spammers to gain enough reputation to actually post a "spammy" answer or question.

Besides, adding a captcha to answer questions will only deter users from answering them. We'd probably lose more genuine users than spammers.

Personally, I don't see what the stack exchange network would gain from adding a reCaptcha.

Comment: has adding captcha to answer  by StackExchange in some sub sites detereed programmers or users in anyway??

Comment: Captcha always deters users. It's an extra step to take before posting an answer. Beiseds, some Captcha's are simply impossible to read.